# How to filter values if are within ranges to add as a new column in data frame

Tags: r

I have a big data frames named "X" and "Y" that look like this:

```
Y <- data.frame(chrom = c(21,21,21,21,21),
            chromStart = c(14720086, 14759761, 14799594, 14847192, 14860997), 
            chromEnd = c(14722086, 14761761, 14801594, 14849192, 14862997),
            TargetGenes = c("ENSG00000185390", "ENSG00000175302",
                            "ENSG00000175302", "ENSG00000219280", "ENSG00000226930"))

X <- data.frame(POS = c(14720573, 14720652, 14721241, 14721279, 14721280))
```

and here what I have tried to do:

```
X$TargetGene <- apply(X$POS, 1, function(v) ifelse(length(k <- which(v >= Y$chromStart & v <= Y$chromEnd))>0,
                as.character(Y$TargetGenes[k]), NA))
```

I am looking for an R solution to check for every row in "X" and finds if X$POS is between Y$chrStart and Y$chrEnd, so then adding the correspond Y$ID to "X" as a new column named "TargetGene".

There may be few values from X$POS that fit into a range in Y data frame. Also, it is possible for some X$POS that do not find any match range in Y data frame.

p.s. the values of Y$chr are the same.

Desired output:

```
> X
POS        TargetGene
14720573   ENSG0000017
14720652   ENSG0000017
14721241      <NA>
15221776   ENSG0000022
```

I do approcciate for any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

```
X$TargetGenes <- apply(X, 1, 
                       function(v) {
                         ifelse(length(k <- which(v >= Y$chromStart & v <= Y$chromEnd)) > 0, 
                                as.character(Y$TargetGenes[k]), 
                                NA)
                         })
```

Comment: Could you post your reproducible sources for both `X` and `Y` in your example?  @davide_Cent

Comment: Hey thanks! I edited the question to add the constructs. Not sure is what you have asked! @ThomaslsCoding

Comment: @davide_Cent I think you should run `apply` with `X` (rather than `X$Pos`). I updated my solution based on your input, and obtained `X$TargetGenes` all with `ENSG00000185390`, since it seems all `POS` of `X` fall into the interval  `14720086` to `14722086`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at fuzzyjoin:

```
data <- tibble(X = 1:5)
iris %>% 
  fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join(data,
                             by = c("Sepal.Length" = "X",
                                    "Sepal.Width" = "X"),
                             match_fun = c(`>`, `<`))
```

However, this might be rather slow, depending on your situation.